# Is there a simple way to slightly lower the output voltage of a e-bike charger?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, charger

For my e-bike (it's actually a scooter) I bought a 71.4V/10A "smart" charger. The original charger is a 70.4V/4A charger (it says it's a 60V charger, but I measured 70.4V and that's about right for a 17p battery pack, since it would charge every cell to about 4.14V).

Instead of the advertised 71.4V, I measured 70.7V which is in fact even better for me since that's a lot closer to the voltage of the original charger.

There is however one problem. After the battery has been charged with the new charger, the bike gives me an "over voltage" error. That's probably the BMS telling the bike that during charging it has seen to high voltages.

I don't think that it's really a problem since the "over voltage" is only 0.3V. But I do like to get rid of the error.

Is there an easy way to lower the voltage of the charger? I checked the charger's board and there are no potentiometers or anything.

Here are some pictures of the charger's PCB:

[image]

[image]

And combined:

[image]

Comment: Is your battery OK for being charged at 10 amps (compared to 4 amps on the original)?

Comment: You can try adding a Schottky diode in series between the charger and the battery. It will have to be a big diode to handle 10 A. It will probably slow down the charging process a bit. But you can try it.

Comment: Yes, the battery is OK for being charged at 10A (there's also an "official" 10A charger).